# Visual Studio intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a problem in visual studio 2012. When I am in the office its intelisense works fine like if I put . it show all the properties and functions but when I logged in from home it stopped showing anything on "." but if write half word and press enter it completes the related object or function. I am having lot of problem as want to see all functions and objects on same page without going to the actual class. I checked the intelisense option on Tools->Option but when I start work in office it starts properly again. This problem is pure technical and related to programming environment.

I always logged in via office domain but at home this login works. Is this the reason this is happening?

Thanks QF

Comment: Are you using Remote Desktop to connect to the office machine?  I suspect that this is feature, not a bug.

Comment: No on my laptop, just login via domain and database via VPN, but not connected to office network, client network using VPN.

Comment: So it doesn't have anything to do with your office, it is just the VS version on your laptop that's borken.  Spin the usual wheel of fortune by disabling add-ins, running setup to repair, reinstall as last resort.